# Image compresser webp in angular

Tags: angular, webp

I am working on uploading images that are mostly taken from Hi-Res Cameras. But it is really increasing the upload time since the file sizes are 5-10MB
I am using angular & I want to compress the image without loss in quality. I came across WebP and thought of implementing a convertor.
I tried using the webp-converter but its not working with angular....so any idea or any other plugin that can help me to overcome this issue.

Answer (score 0):

you can donwload a converter https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/download  for the images, also you can use some online converter like https://cloudconvert.com/webp-converte
for me it doesn't make sense if you want to convert on your angular app the images(tecnically angular doesnt serve images it creates a small server cos angular is a front end framework), cos the computer cost of the convertion it's even heavier than serve heavy images, so the solution is =>
First, convert your images, and then use them on your angular project, from a cdn or serve it static replacing your static images...